# Regex pattern to allow foreign language characters using UTF-8

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pattern-matching

I have the below pattern in a PHP script that works grand:

```
define("PATTERN", "|^['0-9a-zA-Z\\\/\[\]\(\)\=\>\,\'\~\-\^\@\$\%\*\&\?\:\;\_\.\€\+\|\^\@\%\s" . '"' . "]{0,50}$|");
```

I'm trying to allow accented characters in other languages by using the `\p{L}` option but any strings still fail the pattern.

```
define("PATTERN", "|^['0-9\p{L}\\\/\[\]\(\)\=\>\,\'\~\-\^\@\$\%\*\&\?\:\;\_\.\€\+\|\^\@\%\s" . '"' . "]{0,50}$|");
```

Any online regex tester I use says something along the lines of:

> No match groups were extracted.
>
> This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string.

Online example: https://regex101.com/r/nV4yC5/1

Is there a way to allow foreign language characters using UTF-8?

Comment: Can you show your code that is not matching any string?

Comment: Add `u` flag (`|u`) at the end.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, the string is `spółka`

Comment: The online matcher just says you have a match, BTW. Please show the online regex fiddle. And you should really get rid of almost all the escapes in the regex, it looks ugly. Did you think of using `\p{P}` for punctuation, e.g.?

Comment: @stribizhev, https://regex101.com/r/nV4yC5/1 and even with `u` added it's still failing on the pattern.

Comment: Ok, your pattern can be shortened to [`^[0-9\p{L}\\\/\[\]()=>,\'~^@$%*&?:;_.€+|\s\"-]{0,50}$`](https://regex101.com/r/nV4yC5/2), and as for PHP, you can use [this snippet](https://ideone.com/FVmd8z). Does it work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev, that works only if I remove the euro symbol as it gives out about `invalid utf-8 string`.

Comment: I guess you need to save the source files in UTF8.

Comment: @stribizhev, already checked that, the file is saved as UTF-8, it changes the euro symbol to `\x80`

Comment: Please check the [PHP UTF8 cheatsheet](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet). I am afraid, I cannot help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this :

```
|^['0-9\p{L}\\\/\[\]\(\)\=\>\,\'\~\-\^\@\$\%\*\&\?\:\;\_\.\€\+\|\^\@\%\s" . '"' . "]{0,50}$|u
```